# Generate XML Sitemap for Blog on Magento Platform

Tags: plugins, google-xml-sitemaps, magento

Our store is on Magento which is installed at root. Our blog uses Wordpress and is installed at /wp of our domain and renders at /blog. I've tried just about every plugin but cannot generate an xml sitemap for the blog. Each one creates an HTML sitemap of the Magento store without any reference to blog or posts whatsoever.

Our store is [rissyroos.com](http://www.rissyroos.com). The blog location is [rissyroos.com/blog](http://www.rissyroos.com/blog). I've tried at least a dozen different plugins starting and now ending with Yoast. I've tried Google Sitemaps, All in One SEO Pack, Better WordPress Google XML Sitemaps, and numerous other but they all create the same html sitemap. The current sitemap that is being generated by Yoast can be found at /blog/sitemap_index.xml

Thank You in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

> Each one creates an HTML sitemap of the Magento store without any reference to blog or posts whatsoever.

I think you are misunderstanding what is happening here. XML plugins for WP would not go and create arbitrary HTML sitemap. That's just not what they are meant to do.

Since you have two different things in play here I tried to figure out what is what, using a basic check of looking at `body` tag:

- for `www.rissyroos.com/blog/` it is `<body class=" wordpress-index-index is-blog">`. This doesn't look like *normal* WordPress tag, but I suppose it does confirm that this is a WP–driven page.
- for `www.rissyroos.com/blog/sitemap_index.xml` it is `<body class=" amseohtmlsitemap-index-index">`. No mention of WordPress in sight.

My educated guess that however your WP is integrated into Magento site simply interferes with its full functionality, especially that falls under rewrite and custom URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going an integrated plugin route, in my opinion, it'd be easier to just modify your robots.txt to include both the sitemap generated from Magento and the one generated from Wordpress (IMO, I love All in One SEO, but any plugin will work)

You can specify more than one Sitemap file per robots.txt file like so:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/map1.xml

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/map2.xml
```

Reference:  http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

sitemap and robots files are read only from the root directory of your domain. If wordpress is not located there, there is not much that you can do by manipulating wordpress by itself as right now they are controlled by magento.

One solution for your problem is to move wordpress to a subdomain. This way wordpress is controlling the root of the subdomain and whatever plugins you use should give the expected result.

The other option is to generate "manual" `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` files that will direct the search engines to include the relevant sitemaps of magento and wordpress (this is what nicole suggested in his answers, but IMO robots file is the wrong location for that and you should do it in the sitemap file)